# onPanResponderRelease is not working on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anyone please look at my code. I also tried with onPanResponderEnd, is this a issue yet to fixed or i'm doing it wrongly.

//animation

```
const [anim] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY())
```

//panresponder

```
const [pan] =    useState(PanResponder.create({    
                        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
                        onPanResponderMove: (event,gesture)=>{

                    console.log("move")

      },onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
       console.log("release")
       },


     }))
```

//passing animated view to flat list

```
       return (forYouNews.length==0?<SkeletonLoading /> : 
       <Animated.View    {...pan.panHandlers} style={anim.getLayout()}>
       <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:"white"}} keyExtractor={(list)=>list.title} data={forYouNews}
       renderItem={({item,index })=>{ 
  return <Card>    <View style={styles.textView}>    <Text style={{fontSize:12,color:"rgb(29, 132, 242)"}}>{index+1 +".    "}</Text>  
  </View>    <View>
<Image style={styles.img} source={{uri:item.urlToImage==null?oimageicon:item.urlToImage}}></Image>
</View>
   </View>     </Card>

    }}
     > </FlatList>  </Animated.View>
   ) }
```

Comment: Please format your question before posting it on stackoverflow and do not put whole code. Instead of that give more information about your question

Comment: Update your question in more details and put the code that gives error

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :**

- Before posting any question on stackoverflow please be more nice. First of all give more information about your question. After that post the affected or issue having codebase only. Do not put all the code of your file including stylesheet. It will be more easy to answer your question rather than this. :)

**SOLUTION :**

To get it working properly use **`onPanResponderEnd`** instead of **`onPanResponderRelease`**.

Also if we still want to use **`onPanResponderRelease`** then we should allow termination request by:

```
onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true
```

Comment: onPanResponderRelease is still not working after setting onPanResponderTerminationRequest true.

Comment: Read the answer properly. Instead of onPanResponderRelease use onPanResponderEnd

Comment: Yaa... I'm on the problem that require mouse release function. This OnpanresponderEnd will trigger when mouse drag end. OnpanresponderEnd and onPanResponderRelease are not thee same.

Comment: View this - https://medium.com/@hasklin/fixed-react-native-android-panresponder-gestures-not-working-40020d0ae796